# AngularJS not loading into simple hello world

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have looked through many of the tutorials and stack issues, but none of them give an explanation that helps. I think I am missing something small. I have tried other hello world sites for this that use controller.js and app.js but I found this, and I think it should work, and the site said it should. When I type in the data, it doesn't change as it should.

**Note:** at first I downloaded angularjs, but then I read I can just use the src = cnd in instead. Is this true? Do I need to have angular.js in the root folder? The angular portions of the sites never follow through for example the {{}}. Thank you

```
<title>Hello World, AngularJS</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>




Write some text in textbox:
```

```
<h1>Hello {{ sometext }}</h1>
```

Comment: Does your app have more code than the one you put in the question? If yes, could you also add that, as with the current code it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: you should at least define where your applications starts (ng-app) on your html. than place your {{expression}} inside

Answer (score 1):

http://www.angularjsbook.com/angular-basics/chapters/introduction/

I think you should start with some readings ! The following will work.
But then you need to extend step by step with a model, with a controller, and so on...

```
<title>Hello World, AngularJS</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
Write some text in textbox:
<h1>Hello {{ 1+1 }}</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a app.js file . Make a json which contains the data "some text" and this is supplied to html .

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('store',[ ]);
    app.controller('StoreController',function(){
        this.product = gem;
    });

    var gem = {
        sometext:'sometext'
    };


})();
```

HTML

```
<html ng-app="store">
<body>
<div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
      <h1>Hello {{store.product.sometext}}</h1>
</div>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed this:

```
<html ng-app>
```